# need to SUM an SQL statement

Tags: sql, select, sum

I need to use SUM to add up all the salaries in my database. I'm having trouble getting it to work. This is the statement that gives me four lines. All other columns are equal, except "DIRECT SALARY COST." How do I add up the four DIRECT SALARY COST(s) so I can have one unique line?

Here is my code..

```
SELECT C.FOS_PROJ_ID_UNQU||'-'||C.FOS_PROJ_ID_STG||'-'||C.FOS_PROJ_ID_ELMT AS "STATE PROJECT ID",
  V.VEND_NM AS "VENDOR NAME",
  CC.WRKO_NB AS "WORK ORDER NUMBER",
  TO_CHAR(CCD.ATHZ_DT, 'MON-DD-YYYY') AS "AUTHORIZATION DATE",
    ----I need to SUM the following line ----
  TO_CHAR((CTD.DCT_SAL_COST_AMT),'$999,999,999.99') AS "DIRECT SALARY COST",
  TO_CHAR(CCC.OVHD_COST_AMT,'$999,999,999.99') AS "OVERHEAD COSTS",
  TO_CHAR(CTD.DCT_SAL_COST_AMT + CCC.OVHD_COST_AMT,'$999,999,999.99') AS "TOTAL"
FROM DOT1CARO.DT_VEND V, DOT1CARO.DT_CSPJ_CTRC CC, DOT1CARO.DT_CSPJ C, DOT1CARO.DT_CSPJ_CTRC_DTL CCD, DOT1CARO.DT_CSPJ_CTRC_COST CCC, DOT1CARO.DT_CTCST_TASK_DTL CTD
WHERE V.VEND_ID=CC.VEND_ID
AND CC.CSPJ_ID=C.CSPJ_ID
AND CC.CSPJ_CTRC_ID=CCD.CSPJ_CTRC_ID
AND CCD.CSPJ_CTRC_DTL_ID=CCC.CSPJ_CTRC_DTL_ID
AND CCC.CSPJ_CTCST_ID = CTD.CSPJ_CTCST_ID
AND CCD.ATHZ_DT = '14-NOV-2013'
AND V.VEND_NM LIKE 'Ka%
ORDER BY 2;
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of data and desired results.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add multiple fields together in the same row:

```
CTD.DCT_SAL_COST_AMT + CCC.OVHD_COST_AMT + .... AS Combined_Amounts
```

If you want to total them up individually across rows:

```
SELECT NonAggCol1, NonAggCol2, TO_CHAR((SUM(CTD.DCT_SAL_COST_AMT)),'$999,999,999.99') AS "DIRECT SALARY COST"
FROM Table1 a
JOIN Table2 b
  ON a.col1 = b.col1
JOIN Table3 c
  ON a.col1 = c.col1
GROUP BY NonAggCol1, NonAggCol2
```

If you want to add them up within rows and across rows you can combine both of the above.  Be sure to include each non-aggregate field in your `GROUP BY` list. It is a good idea to eliminate the deprecated join syntax.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I didn't realize that I needed to GROUP BY all columns.